# data.plist document is nil when run using different simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

My code runs well when I first time use it with iphone 6 simulator. but when I run it with simulator iphone 5, it throws an error
 "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

this is the line of code that throws the error:

```
let futsalCenterData: [NSData] = NSArray(contentsOfURL: self.dataFileURL()) as! [NSData]
```

is it because it already writes the document in iphone 6 simulator, and the file can only be used inside iphone 6 simulator? if that the case then how can I create one if it not exist in other simulator? and how can I use this function inside iphone?

this is the function inside loader that find the url:

```
    func dataFileURL() -> NSURL {
    //finding the file
    let documentsDirectory: NSURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask ).first!

    //create a new null file called data.plist
    let filePath: NSURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")

    return filePath

}
```

and this is the function that read the file:

```
    func readFutsalCenterFromFile() -> [FutsalCenter] {
    //this line below that throws an error
    let futsalCenterData: [NSData] = NSArray(contentsOfURL: self.dataFileURL()) as! [NSData]
    i

    var futsalCenter: [FutsalCenter] = []

    for data in futsalCenterData{
        let futsal: FutsalCenter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! FutsalCenter
        futsalCenter.append(futsal)
    }
    return futsalCenter
}
```

Comment: You should use as? with guard to unwrap your data.

Comment: Why do you need the data from the other simulator? Why don't you simply generate it again?

Comment: How did `data.plist` get into the iPhone 6 simulator? You need to do that again.